# empty line breaks when trying to scrape with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I was experimenting with puppeteer on youtube and I was trying to scrape the URL src and title text from the thumbnails of the youtube main page and the scraping program works fine. The issue is when it scrapes for the title and src of the thumbnails the program starts to jump lines when logging the URL src but it works fine for the text data. When I tried to understand the line jump recursivity there is a 7 line jump and then a 14 line jump over and over again after every time the program scrapes the information. I can't figure out why the line jump occurs when scraping the URL src but not the text title. Does it have anything to do with my infinite scroll handling method?

```js
async function scrape(url) {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800
  });

  const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation();


  await page.goto(url, {
    timeout: 0
  });

  await page.evaluate(_ => {
    window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
  });
  await page.waitFor(5000);
  await page.waitForSelector('#img')
  await navigationPromise;

  const loadThumbnailText = [];
  const loadThumbnailSrc = [];
  var ytTextData;
  for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    const textSelector = 'h3 > a > #video-title'
    const srcSelector = 'ytd-thumbnail > a > yt-img-shadow > #img'
    await page.waitForSelector(textSelector)
    await page.waitForSelector(srcSelector)
    const ytTextData = await page.$$eval(textSelector, elems => elems.map(el => el.textContent).join('\n'))
    const ytSrcData = await page.$$eval(srcSelector, elems => elems.map(el => el.src).join('\n'))
    if (ytTextData && ytSrcData) {
      console.log({
        ytTextData,
        ytSrcData
      })
      loadThumbnailText.push(ytTextData);
      loadThumbnailSrc.push(ytSrcData);
      console.log(ytTextData, ytSrcData)
    }
  }

  browser.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with the selectors you have.  I ran the following in the console on youtube.com:

```
document.querySelectorAll('h3 > a > #video-title').length
document.querySelectorAll('ytd-thumbnail > a > yt-img-shadow > #img').length
```

The first gave me 29 and the second 42.  It looks like there are hidden videos on the homepage, that only show up on clicking a down-arrow.  Your text selector is picking up those videos but your source selector is not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get video titles you need just extract them from the correct selectors, but if you need to get images `src`, you need to [scroll video thumbnails into view](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-youtube-search-video-results-with-nodejs/#code_explanation). You can do like in the code below ([also check it on the online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Scrape-YouTube-main-page-titles-and-thumbs-with-NodeJS#index.js)):

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

const mainPageUrl = "https://www.youtube.com";

async function scrollPage(page, scrollElements) {
  let currentElement = 0;
  while (true) {
    let elementsLength = await page.evaluate((scrollElements) => {
      return document.querySelectorAll(scrollElements).length;
    }, scrollElements);
    for (; currentElement < elementsLength; currentElement++) {
      await page.waitForTimeout(200);
      await page.evaluate(
        (currentElement, scrollElements) => {
          document.querySelectorAll(scrollElements)[currentElement].scrollIntoView();
        },
        currentElement,
        scrollElements
      );
    }
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
    let newElementsLength = await page.evaluate((scrollElements) => {
      return document.querySelectorAll(scrollElements).length;
    }, scrollElements);
    if (newElementsLength === elementsLength || currentElement > 100) break; // if you want to get all elements (or some other number of elements) change number to 'Infinity' (or some other number)
  }
}

async function getThumbnailsAndTitles() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(60000);
  await page.goto(mainPageUrl);
  await page.waitForSelector("#contents");
  const scrollElements = "a#thumbnail";
  await scrollPage(page, scrollElements);
  await page.waitForTimeout(10000);
  const videosData = await page.$$eval("#contents > ytd-rich-item-renderer", (els) => els.map(el => ({
      title: el.querySelector('#video-title').textContent.trim(),
      thumbnail: el.querySelector('a#thumbnail #img').getAttribute('src'),
    })).filter(el => el.thumbnail));
  await browser.close();
  return videosData;
}

getThumbnailsAndTitles().then(console.log);
```

Output

```json
[
   {
      "title":"Here's Why You Never Mess With A Guard Of The Tomb Of The Unknown Soldier",
      "thumbnail":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NkFusHg8b_Y/hq720.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCNAFEJQDSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLA_oEpmdhM1EJj2jfzjkBFsPP1o0g"
   },
   {
      "title":"4 Hours of Music For Studying, Concentration And Work - Ambient Study Music to Concentrate",
      "thumbnail":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m80E1K75vDI/hq720.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCNAFEJQDSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLA337Z-2wa3XFpKtKHbW9CAJlGhCw"
   },
   {
      "title":"SIDEMEN HIDE AND SEEK IN A SCHOOL",
      "thumbnail":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/v3vWfuyGI4E/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCOADEI4CSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLBHQa8X226RJsQGbT-m9oJvESJVag"
   },
    ...and other results
]
```

You can read more about scraping YouTube search results from my blog post [Web scraping YouTube search video results with Nodejs](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-youtube-search-video-results-with-nodejs/).